# Hibernate interceptor and event listeners

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, listener

I wonder if it's possible to find out what hibernate *really* did to the database (i.e., committed changes). I'd like to notify another process on certain changes.

I guess that the [EventType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/spi/EventType.html)s `POST_COMMIT_DELETE`, `POST_COMMIT_UPDATE` and `POST_COMMIT_INSERT` should do, but given exactly zero documentation, it's only a guess. Can someone confirm? Am I missing any?

I'm also unsure about how to obtain what gets really written. The `PostInsertEvent` contains both `Object entity` and `Object[] state`, which of the two should I trust?

---

A side question: I'm using no XML, no Spring, no JPA, just `Configuration` and `buildSessionFactory`. Is this really the way listeners should be registered?

```
 EventListenerRegistry registry = ((SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory)
    .getServiceRegistry()
    .getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
registry.appendListeners(....);
```

I'm asking as its 1. dependent on an implementation detail, 2 totally ugly, 3. nearly perfectly undiscoverable.

Comment: Have you tried this http://www.wideskills.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptors-and-events

Answer (score 19):

**Yes**, it is possible to notify another process(For Example: Auditing) after committing certain changes in the DB. That is to do certain things right after the JDBC transaction(Hibernate wraps JDBC transaction ) is committed using **Custom Interceptors** and **Events** of Hibernate.

You can create your own custom interceptor class by extending it by **EmptyInterceptor** class of hibernate. And by overriding the below afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) method of EmptyInterceptor to do certain tasks after the transaction has been committed.

```
public class AuditLogInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
 @Override
 public void afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
    System.out.println("Task to do after transaction ");
 }
}
```

---

The **Event** system can be used in addition, or as a replacement, for interceptors.

#### Below listed are few ways to perform certain task after transaction event is completed/committed

**1**.Implement **AfterTransactionCompletionProcess** interface from org.hibernate.action package and implement the below method. [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/action/AfterTransactionCompletionProcess.html)

```
void doAfterTransactionCompletion(boolean success, SessionImplementor session) {
      //Perform whatever processing is encapsulated here after completion of the transaction.
}
```

Otherwise, you can extend your CustomDeleteAction class with **EntityDeleteAction** and override the above doAfterTransactionCompletion method. [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/action/EntityDeleteAction.html)

**2**.By Implementing **PostDeleteEventListener** and using `EventType.POST_COMMIT_DELETE`for post delete.
By Implementing **PostInsertEventListener** and using `EventType.POST_COMMIT_INSERT`for post insert.
By Implementing **PostUpdateEventListener** and using `EventType.POST_COMMIT_UPDATE`for post update.
Here are few examples of [PostDeleteEventListener](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.hibernate.event.spi.PostDeleteEventListener)
, [PostUpdateEventListener](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.hibernate.event.PostUpdateEventListener) and [PostInsertEventListener](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.hibernate.event.PostInsertEventListener).

---

The `Object entity` of PostInsertEvent gives the entity involved in the database operation.

The `Object[] state` of PostInsertEvent returns the session event source for this event. This is the underlying session from which this event was generated.
Below link contains the documentation for PostInsertEvent Members.

http://mausch.github.io/nhibernate-3.2.0GA/html/6deb23c7-79ef-9599-6cfd-6f45572f6894.htm

---

**Registering event listeners**: Below MyIntegrator class shows **3 ways** to register event listeners.

```
public class MyIntegrator implements org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator {

public void integrate(Configuration configuration, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
    // As you might expect, an EventListenerRegistry is the thing with which event listeners are registered  
    // It is a service so we look it up using the service registry
    final EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry = serviceRegistry.getService( EventListenerRegistry.class );

    // If you wish to have custom determination and handling of "duplicate" listeners, you would have to add an
    // implementation of the org.hibernate.event.service.spi.DuplicationStrategy contract like this
    eventListenerRegistry.addDuplicationStrategy( myDuplicationStrategy );

    // EventListenerRegistry defines 3 ways to register listeners:
    //     1) This form overrides any existing registrations with
    eventListenerRegistry.setListeners( EventType.AUTO_FLUSH, myCompleteSetOfListeners );
    //     2) This form adds the specified listener(s) to the beginning of the listener chain
    eventListenerRegistry.prependListeners( EventType.AUTO_FLUSH, myListenersToBeCalledFirst );
    //     3) This form adds the specified listener(s) to the end of the listener chain
    eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners( EventType.AUTO_FLUSH, myListenersToBeCalledLast );
}
}
```

Hence, Listeners registration to a event is dependent on implementation detail.

Comment: What is the difference between the `EventType.POST_UPDATE` and  `EventType.POST_COMMIT_UPDATE`?

Comment: @Superole, As this is different question apart from the current thread. I've raised this question as a new one. Please go through it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533444/what-is-the-difference-between-the-eventtype-post-update-and-eventtype-post-comm