# Hibernate not executing queries until response is commited

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am doing few hibernate save operations in spring's transactional service class.
My expectation is that by the time method execution finishes hibernate should write data to database.
But hibernate is actually executing those queries only when controller is about to return a response.

My sample code is as follows.

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private SaveService saveService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "saveData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveData(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        try {       
        saveService.saveData(object1, object2, object3); // LINE 1
        sendEmail();                                     // LINE 2
        //some code here                 // LINE 3  
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //log exception
            //return error message      
        }
    }
}


@Service("saveService")
@Transactional
public class SaveServiceImpl implements SaveService {
    @Autowired
    private SaveDAO saveDAO;

    public void saveData(Object objec1, Object objec2, Object objec3) {
        saveDAO.save(object1);
        saveDAO.save(object2);
        saveDAO.save(object3);  
    }   
}
```

In above code I am calling SaveService.saveData() method from controller. And if save is successful I want to go ahead and send an email. But if for some reason SaveService.saveData() throws an exception i don't want
to send the email.
When I performed some tests it was observed that even if SaveService.saveData() throws an exception it's not thrown 
until the email is sent from controller. 
 I want that if a call to saveService.saveData() at 'LINE 1' in controller 
throws an exception the next line that sends email should not get executed. 
I wanted to know if this is expected hibernate behavior and if it is what can I do to tell hibernate to execute
queries before exiting service methods.
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out why it doesn't work. But I can advise you to use `@TransactionalEventListener` [(Details here)](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2#transaction-bound-events) to perform some operations just after the transaction has been committed or rolled back

Comment: which exception is thrown? I guess its NullPointerException.

Comment: Thanks @Dekart. Going through the link you shared.

Comment: @Rohit i am deliberately generating exception like primaryKey violation etc in the service method to test the code. I want to ensure that if there is an exception in service method (saveData()) the email is not sent.

Comment: @ivish, to perform certain operations right after the transaction has been committed you can use hibernates events and interceptors. here is link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501074/hibernate-interceptor-and-event-listeners/39618826#39618826 that I have listed some possible ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is due to hibernate optimizations. Hibernate will wait until the last time possible to execute the sentences.

You can avoid this with *session.flush()*, Flushing the session forces Hibernate to synchronize the in-memory state of the Session with the database (i.e. to write changes to the database).

Comment: yes, i am aware that calling session.flush() would force hibernate to commit transaction right away. But i wanted to avoid that so as not to miss out on any optimizations that hibernate may be performing without session.flush().

Comment: session.flush() does not commit the transaction, only save the data to the DB in the current session. Do you have some prove that sendEmail() method is fired independently of if it execute well or wrong ? I think that's no possible.

Comment: I tested code couple of times by generating a primary key violation db exception. Exception was NOT thrown until line that sends email was executed. Finally i am using @TransactionalEventListener to send emails after transaction is committed as suggestd by [@Dekart](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1851902/dekart)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is when an exception occurs, your the variables/objects are not initialized in the catch block and you are accessing it.

As it looks like you have just added a snippet of the code in question, so I guess the variables `object1, object2, object3` needs to initalized to `null`.
**for example:** `object1=null`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rohit. The code i posted is not the actual code but just an example to demonstrate the problem i am facing. The objects are entities like User, Role etc in my code and they are fully initialized before they are passed to service method.