# What is the difference between the EventType.POST_UPDATE and EventType.POST_COMMIT_UPDATE in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

This question was raised in comment section of [Hibernate interceptor and event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501074/hibernate-interceptor-and-event-listeners/39618826#39618826)
.

Below is my answer on that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `POST_COMMIT_UPDATE` and `POST_UPDATE` are the events of type `PostUpdateEventListener` that occurs after the datastore is updated.

**1)** The `POST_COMMIT_UPDATE` should be used, if after transaction hooks need to be registered.
The method [requiresPostCommitHandling](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/spi/PostUpdateEventListener.html#requiresPostCommitHandling-org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityPersister-) returns true if after transaction callbacks should be added.
Here, is an [example](https://www.javatips.net/api/esi4j-master/src/main/java/at/molindo/esi4j/module/hibernate/DefaultHibernateLifecycleInjector.java) that depicts the use of `POST_COMMIT_UPDATE`.

**2)** The plain `POST_UPDATE` event is triggered based on hibernate flushing logic.
Here is an [example](https://www.javatips.net/api/bygle-ldp-master/src/main/java/org/bygle/db/listener/HibernateListenersConfigurer.java) of `POST_UPDATE`.